# Why does symfony container has service duplicates?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to register class `App\Service\SomeService` as a service.

Here is my `services.yaml`:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: false
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
    someservice:
        class: App\Service\SomeService
```

Now I run `debug:container someservice`:

```
Information for Service "someservice"
=====================================

 ---------------- ------------------------- 
  Option           Value                    
 ---------------- ------------------------- 
  Service ID       someservice              
  Class            App\Service\SomeService  
  Tags             -                        
  Public           yes                      
  Synthetic        no                       
  Lazy             no                       
  Shared           yes                      
  Abstract         no                       
  Autowired        no                       
  Autoconfigured   yes                      
 ---------------- -------------------------
```

But also, when I run `debug:container App\\Service\\SomeService`:

```
Information for Service "App\Service\SomeService"
=================================================

 ---------------- ------------------------- 
  Option           Value                    
 ---------------- ------------------------- 
  Service ID       App\Service\SomeService  
  Class            App\Service\SomeService  
  Tags             -                        
  Public           yes                      
  Synthetic        no                       
  Lazy             no                       
  Shared           yes                      
  Abstract         no                       
  Autowired        no                       
  Autoconfigured   yes                      
 ---------------- -------------------------
```

So it turns out I have another service pointing to the same class:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use App\Service\SomeService;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        var_dump($this->get('someservice') === $this->get(SomeService::class));
        return new Response;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> bool(false)

Why do I have two services registered instead of one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you registered it twice in your `services.yaml`.

Once automatically with this line:

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

The other, manually:

```
someservice:
    class: App\Service\SomeService
```

Since they have different name (`someservice` and `App\Service\SomeService`), they're different for Symfony.

I suggest you to remove the second declaration and to only call the service with its fully qualified name in your controller: `$this->get(SomeService::class)`